# Gstreamer souphttpsrc to rtp h263 encoded stream

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to create a pipeline for streaming a jpeg stream into h263 encoded stream over RTP. When I execute:

```
gst-launch -v \
    souphttpsrc \
        location=http://192.168.1.54:8080 \
        do-timestamp=true \
    ! multipartdemux ! image/jpeg,width=352,height=288 \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=15/1 \
    ! videoscale \
    ! ffenc_h263 ! rtph263pay \
    ! udpsink host=192.168.1.31 port=1234
```

gstreamer reports:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter2: caps = image/jpeg, width=(int)352, height=(int)288
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:souphttpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2507): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:souphttpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMultipartDemux:multipartdemux0.GstPad:src_0: caps = NULL
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I've checked that the elements are existing. I've run gst-inspect for ffenc_h263, ffmpegcolorspace and the rest of the elements in this command too. gst-inspect does not report any error.
Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

1. You need `jpegdec` after `multipartdemux` to decode jpeg stream into raw video.
2. You don't need `ffmpegcolorspace` because `jpegdec` converts to `video/x-raw-yuv`.
3. `videoscale` is useless here, because you do not specify width/height for outgoing stream.

Try this:

```
gst-launch -v \
    souphttpsrc \
        location=http://192.168.1.54:8080 \
        do-timestamp=true \
    ! multipartdemux \
    ! image/jpeg,width=352,height=288,framerate=15/1 \
    ! jpegdec ! ffenc_h263 ! rtph263pay \
    ! udpsink host=192.168.1.31 port=1234
```